# Is it possible to create themes for android mobile

Tags: android, themes, firmware

I have googled and gone through some of the posts, im not clear about creating the themes for the android phone.
 I just want to create the themes for the android mobile. Not necessary to be an app.
As far as i know the *HTC Desire HD* consists the option of theme(In that it is named as skins).
 My question is 
**How to create a theme for the android mobile?** 
**Can we do that programatically?** if so provide me some samples
If we cant create programatically then **Wat is the procedure to create the theme?**
 and i want to know that whether i can do something like **Firmware Modification**. If firmware modification is possible **how can i do tat?**

Help me out..

I have gone through this [Link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=801928) but i cant able to figure it out right.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this link, it might help you; http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=466586